identify a comment between /* and */ that may contain */ inside of it only if it's inside ""
I am working on a lexical analyser but i am struggling on how to identify the comments as below:

A comment is a sequence of characters (even space) between /* and */; it may not contain the sub-string */ unless it is between double quotes like this "*/".

I only could do these two attempts:
pattern commentPattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*.?\\*/"); // it identify the comment between /* and */

and this attempt:
pattern commentPattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*.? \\"\\*/ .?  \\*/");

Can you please help?

Redefine the language. You should not permit nested comments at all, nor have to parse them for quotation marks.

Agreed, this is a pernicious requirement.  Also, regex tends not to work for complicated parsing.  You'll eventually end up with cases it just can't handle.  Time to be thinking about using a full parser for this language parsing task.

I missed that you are trying to do this with a regular expression. That certainly won't work. You need a DPDA for this, not an NFA/DFA. And consider that comments can be arbitrarily long, spread over many lines. And you don't write lexical analysers with multiple Patterns in the first place. You're on the wrong track entirely.

Can you also have quotes within quotes, and how are they represented? (Like in Java you would use backslash-quote for one.) I assume that the quotes may contain more than just the */?

@user207421 I’m not convinced that it’s not doable with regex; but it will be tricky and unreadable, which alone is a reason to avoid it if possible.

user:5772882 Pattern.compile("/\(?:(?!\/)[^"]|"[^"]")\*/") this really works !! i can't thank you enough for this answer

@user207421 It has been made to work. Please see the OP’s own answer.

Fortunatly an anounymous member gave me an answer that worked for me, here it is:
Pattern.compile("/\\*(?:(?!\\*/)[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*\\*/")

The regular expression matches in order:

/
*
0 or more repetitions of something that is either:

not starting just before */ (via negative look-ahead) and is a char that is not "
a " followed by 0 or more chars that are not " followed by " -- in short, a quoted string (that may or may not contain */)


*
/

Demonstration in Java:
    Pattern commentPattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*(?:(?!\\*/)[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*\\*/");

    String test = "before * / * /* inside * a / \" in quote */ \" still in comment * */ after";
    Matcher matcher = commentPattern.matcher(test);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No comment found");
    }

Output is:

/* inside * a / " in quote */ " still in comment * */


